# Biot - Savart Law and time - variable current

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, electric-current

Is the Biot Savart law valid also with currents which are functions of time (for instance a sine wave)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the Biot-Savart law is only valid in magnetostatics, i.e. when there are no time-varying currents. Jefimenko's equations need to be solved instead.

However, in the quasi-static approximation of electromagnetism which is valid for currents with time variations that are "sufficiently slow", it is safe to use the Biot-Savart law. One way of judging the validity of the quasi-static approximation is by comparing the system size to the wavelength associated with time scales of interest ($\lambda = c/f$, where $f$ is a dominant frequency with which the current is varying and $c$ is the speed of light in the relevant medium, often air/vacuum). If the system is much smaller compared to this wavelength, the quasi-static approximation typically works very well.

Comment: Hello, I have a pair of questions which are similar to that I asked in this topic. Is the coulomb law for electric field (E = k Q/r^2) true also in electrodynamics (Q = Q(t))? Moreover, consider a conductor which is supplied with a DC voltage: are we in electrostatics (since current is constant in time) or electrodynamics (since charges move)?

Comment: Coulomb's law is not strictly valid in electrodynamics. Again, Jefimenko's equations are what you would use instead. Steady currents are usually the realm of magnetostatics, but I don't know what best to call it if you're only concerned with the E-field, perhaps a special case of electrodynamics. What is important is that all fields in this case are static, and this means you can use Coulomb's law to calculate the E-field due to a fixed charge distribution even in the presence of DC currents.